# Dynamically load google maps api v3 with namespaced callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, google-maps-api-3

I recently ran across the following problem when lazy loading/dynamically loading the google maps api v3: In order to check whether the api has fully loaded or not, I followed the [instructions](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#Async) on google's documentation page. Works fine with a normal function callback name like **&callback=initialize** in global scope. Also works fine with a function callback that is within a certain namespace like **&callback=Namespace.initialize**.

Now my function is placed under **Namespace.foo[0].initialize** ("Namespace" and "foo" are of type object). The problem now is that I can't properly access this function. I tried several ways of building the callback string, each listed below with whatever firebug tells me is not working:

```
&callback=Namespace.foo[0].initialize
Firebug: NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - <http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3...&callback=Namespace.foo[0].initialize...>

&callback=Namespace.foo.0.initialize
Firebug: missing ; before statement
Firebug: [Break On This Error] window.Namespace.foo[0].initialize()

&callback=Namespace.foo%5B0%5D.initialize
Firebug: NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - <http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3...&callback=Namespace.foo[0].initialize...>
```

I'm thankful for every hint and/or solution!

> > *Background information: What I do might also be interesting. A script is dynamically loading html, css, data and the google maps api into a external webpage (within a web-widget). Now I'm using jQuery's deferred object to queue the different includes such as loading the css/javascript/html first, then receive the data and finally setup the google map within the previously loaded structure. Deferred object performs way better than handling the different steps with callbacks (and much easier too!), but when the jQuery.getScript method is done (loads the google maps api) the success event is fired and deferred.resolve gets returned. Too bad that this probably just handles the authentification (via client-key) and then asynchronously loads the google maps main.js. This pretty much sucks because I need to wait for the api to fully load...*

Comment: foo[0] refers to an Array or an Object?  If the latter could you just do Namespace.foo.0.initialize?

Comment: It refers to an object. The object "foo" is dynamically filled with another object; 0 comes from the jQuery.each function that provides a numeric key (and value in the callback function) that I use to create foo[0] - foo[n].

Comment: Btw. look at example #2: I did in fact try to do Namespace.foo.0.initialize and it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you assign your callback function to another variable, and pass that to Google?  e.g. var myFunction = namespace.foo[0].initialize;